# Angular stop and resume html checking

Tags: angular, angular7, primeng

I have a big table with a lot of cells. Each cell has a spcefic color, that can change depending of the value of some methods. Also, there are elements in the table that can be dragged, with the primeng dragdrop, from cell to cell.

That is the html code:

```
<tr ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="rows" let-i="index">
  <td *ngFor="let col of cols" class="{{checkA(col,row) ? 'styleA' : checkN(col,row) ? 'styleN' : ...}} 
   pDroppable="foo" (onDrop)="drop(col,row)">
    <div pDraggable="foo *ngIf="getFoo(col, row) != null" (onDragStart)="dragStart(col,row)" (onDragEnd)="dragEnd()">
      {{foo.name}}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And that the js code:

```
dragStart(col, row) {
  this.select.col= col; 
  this.select.row= row;
}

dragEnd(event) {
  this.select = null;
}

drop(col, row) {
  this.move(this.select.col, this.select.row, col, row);
  this.select = null;
}
```

The table is so big, and the checks doesnt always return the same value, so after every change in the table all the cells have to be checked. The problem is that all the cells are checked every time some value changes in the js, like when the event dragStart happens. This does'nt affect the html, but all the cells are checked again, taking like ten seconds to start the drag.
Is there any way to stop angular from checking every cell at the start of the dragStart and resume it later, when there will be (or not) some change in the table? 
Something like this:

```
dragStart(col, row) {
  this.select.col= col; 
  this.select.row= row;
  this.stopChecking();
}

dragEnd() {
  this.select = null;
  this.resumeChecking();
}

drop(col, row) {
  this.move(this.select.col, this.select.row, col, row);
  this.select = null;
  this.resumeChecking();
}
```

The angular version is 7.2.15 and the primeng version is 6.1.7

Comment: you can look into Angular's onPush change detection strategy. Here's the link i used https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: I think that the third option in the link could work for the project, thanks for sharing it.